# How to slide one by one LI's as prev and next using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-1.5

I am trying to slide list items as previous and next one by one. My example will look like below

```
  < Li1 List 2 ulList 3 List 4 Li5 >
```

After click on Next(greaterthanIcon) Li1 should be hide then

```
  < List 2 ulList 3 List 4 Li5 List6 >
```

If I click on previous(lesserthanIcon) Li1 should come and List6 should hide.

my code is:

HTML:

```
      <div class="left"><</div>
         <div id="listWrapper">
           <ul>
             <li>Li1</li>
             <li>List 2</li>
             <li>ulList 3</li>
             <li>List 4</li>
             <li>Li5</li>
             <li>List6</li>
             <li>Li7</li>
             <li>List8</li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       <div class="right">></div>
```

CSS:

```
       <style type="text/css">
          #listWrapper{
             width:225px;
             overflow:hidden;
            }

             ul{
              white-space: nowrap;
            }
          li{
            display:inline-block;
            }
          .left {
            position: relative;
            top: 34px;
            left: 23px;
            }
         .right {
          position: relative;
          top: -34px;
          left: 230px;
           }
      </style>
```

Comment: Where's your JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: The easiest way - find some carousel script, there are tones of them: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/, for free, and use it.